# 3DES and RSA encryption of values for Web Service work in C# but not in Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, rsa, tripledes

I have a requirement in which I have to communicate with a 
Web Service by sending three parameters that are encrypted: `ID`, `key` and `initialization vector (IV)`. In order to do this, I need to use `Triple DES (3DES/DESede)` encryption as well as `RSA` encryption. The steps required to do this are:

1. Start with the ID in clear text. Decode the ID from a base64 string to an array of bytes. The original ID is not base64 encoded but this step must be performed.
2. Encrypt the base64 decoded ID using 3DES and generate the key and IV
3. Encrypt the key and IV generated with RSA (using a certificate provided)

   4. Convert encrypted ID, encrypted key and IV to base64 strings.

I was provided with a C# example on how to do this and the code looks as displayed below:

```
namespace SampleEncryption
{
  public class SampleWebServiceInvocation
   {
    private const string CERT_SUBJECT = "sample.cer";

    public string GetReport()
    {
        ReportService.RService ws = new ReportService.RService();

        ReportService.ReportRequest req = new ReportService.ReportRequest();

        string key = string.Empty;
        string iv = string.Empty;

        string id = "1234567890123456";

        string encrypt = new CryptEx().EncryptEx(id, CERT_SUBJECT, ref key, ref iv);
        req.AccountNumber = encrypt;
        req.Key = key;
        req.InitializationVector = iv;

        ReportService.ReportResponse resp = ws.getReport(req);

        if (resp.Success)
            return resp.RedirectUrl;

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// CryptorEx
/// </summary>
public class CryptEx
{
    private X509Certificate2 _certificate;
    private byte[] _encryptedKey;
    private byte[] _encryptedIV;
    private byte[] _encryptedText;
    private byte[] _decryptedKey;
    private byte[] _decryptedIV;
    private byte[] _decryptedText;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default (empty) constructor 
    /// </summary>
    public CryptEx()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publicly exposed encrypt method
    /// </summary>
    public string EncryptEx(string decryptedText, string certSubject, ref string key, ref string iv)
    {
        string data;
        _decryptedText = Convert.FromBase64String(decryptedText);

        try
        {
            _certificate = GetSignerCert(certSubject);
            _encryptedText = EncryptWithTripleDES();
            EncryptWithRSA();

            key = Convert.ToBase64String(_encryptedKey);
            iv = Convert.ToBase64String(_encryptedIV);
            data = Convert.ToBase64String(_encryptedText);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            data = string.Empty;
        }
        return data;
    }

    private byte[] EncryptWithTripleDES()
    {
        //Create a crypto provider for the text
        using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            tripDes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();

            //Encrypt
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(_decryptedText, 0, _decryptedText.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                cs.Close();
                ms.Close();

                _decryptedKey = tripDes.Key;
                _decryptedIV = tripDes.IV;
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    private void EncryptWithRSA()
    {
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_certificate.PublicKey.Key)
        {
            _encryptedKey = rsa.Encrypt(_decryptedKey, false);
            _encryptedIV = rsa.Encrypt(_decryptedIV, false);
        }
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 GetSignerCert(string certName)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            // First, find certificates that haven't expired
            X509Certificate2Collection validCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

            X509Certificate2Collection scorecardCerts = validCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, false);

            if (scorecardCerts.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unable to find certificate with name of {0}", certName));

            if (scorecardCerts.Count > 1)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("More than one certificate has a name of {0}\r\n{1}",
                                                    certName, GetSubjectNames(scorecardCerts)));

            return scorecardCerts[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
    }

    private static string GetSubjectNames(X509Certificate2Collection signingCert)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in signingCert)
            sb.AppendLine(cert.Subject);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

In my case, I need to do this but in Java, so here I expose the logic of my implementation.

For Triple DES:

```
public class DESedeCrypto implements SymmetricCryptoManager {

/**
 * Constant for the algorithm being used for Triple DES (CBC)
 */
public static final String DESEDE_CBC_TRANSFORMATION_ALG = "DESede/CBC/NoPadding";

@Override
public DESedeEncryptionResult encrypt(byte[] srcData, String cryptoAlgorithm) throws Exception {
    DESedeEncryptionResult result = null;
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    byte[] initializationVector = null;

    if (srcData == null || srcData.length == 0) {
        throw new InvalidEncryptionTargetException();
    }

    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cryptoAlgorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

    result = new DESedeEncryptionResult();

    if (cryptoAlgorithm.equals(DESEDE_CBC_TRANSFORMATION_ALG)) {
        IvParameterSpec spec = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
        initializationVector = spec.getIV();
        result.setInitializationVector(initializationVector);
    }

    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(srcData);

    result.setResultBytes(encryptedBytes);
    result.setKeyBytes(secretKey.getEncoded());

    return result;
}

}
```

For RSA:

```
public class RSACrypto implements AsymmetricCryptoManager {

/**
 * Tranformation algorithm for OAEP.
 */
private static final String OAEP_RSA_TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";

/**
 * Constructor of the class.
 */
public RSACrypto() {
}

@Override
public byte[] encryptWithCertificate(InputStream inputStream, byte[] targetBytes) throws Exception {
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    if (targetBytes == null || targetBytes.length == 0) {
        throw new InvalidEncryptionTargetException();
    }

    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new InvalidCertificatePathException("Resource specified for operation is not valid");
    }

    X509Certificate certificate = CryptoUtils.readCertificateFromInputStream(inputStream);
    encryptedBytes = getEncryptedBytes(certificate, targetBytes);

    return encryptedBytes;
}

private byte[] getEncryptedBytes(X509Certificate certificate, byte[] targetBytes) throws Exception {
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(OAEP_RSA_TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(targetBytes);

    return encryptedBytes;
}

}
```

Here's how I read the certificate:

```
public static X509Certificate readCertificateFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    X509Certificate certificate = null;

    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance(X509_CERT_TYPE);
    certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);

    return certificate;
}
```

And here is the logic of the whole encryption process:

```
String base64id = new String(CryptoUtils.encodeBase64(base64id.getBytes()));
DESedeEncryptionResult encryptionResult = desedeCrypto.encrypt(CryptoUtils.decodeBase64(base64id), DESedeCrypto.DESEDE_CBC_TRANSFORMATION_ALG);
byte[] rsaEncryptedKey = rsaCrypto.encryptWithCertificate(certForKeyInputStream, encryptionResult.getKeyBytes());
            byte[] rsaEncryptedIv = rsaCrypto.encryptWithCertificate(certForIvInputStream, encryptionResult.getInitializationVector());

String encryptedId = CryptoUtils.getBase64EncodedStr(encryptionResult.getResultBytes());
String finalEncryptedKey = CryptoUtils.getBase64EncodedStr(rsaEncryptedKey);
String finalIv = CryptoUtils.getBase64EncodedStr(rsaEncryptedIv);
```

The ID used for testing is: `1234567890123456`

When I send the results to the Web Service I receive a message that the encryption cannot be done. In order to make sure, I tested both implementations (Java and c#). C# generated values are working when I send them to the web service, but Java implementation is not working.

Do you know if there's some specific type of algorithm I'd need to add to the Java implementation, I mean in Triple DES we use DESede/CBC/NoPadding but maybe c# uses another. Same for RSA.

Maybe somebody can give a me clue or recommendation regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: C# uses by default PKCS padding and ECB encoding if I don't recall it wrong.

Comment: C# seems to use PKC7Padding by default. The java equivalent is called "PKCS5Padding" but don't fret over the name, it's really PKCS7 padding. Your java transform string should be "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding".

Comment: And if you do fret, see my [Q/A over at crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).

Comment: Thanks all for your support. I've changed the DESede to use PKCS5PAdding and it works for the communication, I'm not receiving a error in encryption message from their side, but I received a message from the service saying the ID must have 16 digits even when the String I used has 16 digits, but I think that's something I need to check with the dev team of the external service. I didn't need to change the RSA btw.